# How to delete unreleased version of iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I created a new app version `1.6.1` in AppStoreConnect, but never uploaded a binary or entered review. After some time I decided that the next version should rather be a `1.7.0`. Is there a way to delete the old version `1.6.1` and create a new one instead? (As long as the old version is around I cannot create a new one, and changing the version number in-place is not supported).

([Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870408/delete-new-version-of-app-in-itunes-connect) have been asked, but the platform is constantly changing, rendering year-old answers useless more often than not.)

Comment: The top-rated answer on the question you linked to is the answer; Simply go into your 1.6.1 app in App Store Connect and change its version number to 1.7.0

Comment: @Paulw11I indeed, I completely overlooked that this option still exists -- I assumed it had gone and thus asked again. Thanks for pointing out that this still works :)