# App Store Connect: cancel submission after rejection

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I created a new app version, but this one got rejected by the App Store review team. To fix the issue some more effort has to be put in, but the company doesn't want to do that in this hotfix release. Now I should cancel this version all together for the App Store only.

How do I do skip this version?

The "submit for review" button is available, but I want to abort the submission. Should I remove the build as [described here](https://nosuchstudio.medium.com/how-to-remove-a-rejected-version-from-apple-store-connect-c8d73bf031ad) and then I can remove the version somehow? Or should I overwrite the version number and submit a new build with the new version as [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40400546/426227)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the build (for submission) from the [App Store page](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) and updated all descriptions/screenshots including the displayed version number.

Afterwards, I submitted a new build with the updated version number. This worked like a charm! The old (rejected) version never existed :-)